# Add spacing into list of figures for each section

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, sectioning

I am writing my project report and in my list of figures I need space between each sections, but I am not getting space between each section. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{Report}
%\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}%%%
\usepackage{wrapfig}%%%
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
%\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{array}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\newenvironment{bottompar}{\par\vspace*{\fill}}{\clearpage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Contents}
\cleardoublepage
%list of figures page****************************
%\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
```

Answer (score 0):

After each `\section` add `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}`.

This will insert a vertical space of 10pt between each set of figure titles in the LoF.

If you got bored with that you could change the `\section` command to include doing the `\addtocontents`.

If you need similar spaces in your LoT include `\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}`

```
% lofprob.tex  SE 564815

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\section{First}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}

\begin{figure}
\centering
ILLSTRATION
\caption{First}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
ILLSTRATION
\caption{Second}
\end{figure}

\section{Second}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}

\begin{figure}
\centering
ILLSTRATION
\caption{First}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
ILLSTRATION
\caption{Second}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! actually this is not adding the desires space in the list of figures. I have modified the code like: \section{Introduction}
\addtocontents{lof}{\addvspace{10pt}}

Comment: @LokeshVakkalakula My apologies. I missed out a `\protect` and have edited my answer to provide a full MWE that works. I haven't tried it with your document's preamble as somehow SE only let me copy part of it. Hope all will be OK this time.

Comment: -It worked. Thanks a lot!:)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong class? That is what a book-like class usually does by default with figures of different chapters (not of sections). If you do not like the usual chapter style in your document, then `scrbook` or `memoir` class are good alternatives to have section-like chapters without headaches, and if start the chapters in a new page is also a problem (it should not be a problem in documents of some entity), it is easily solvable too:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{One}}
\begin{figure}[h]\caption{aaa}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]\caption{bbb}\end{figure}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Two}}
\begin{figure}[h]\caption{ccc}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]\caption{ddd}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```